# IE9 specific bug - offscreen list items shifting when mousedown

Tags: javascript, html, css, list, internet-explorer-9

I've run into a really peculiar bug that's only affecting IE9 (IE8 is fine surprisingly).

I have a series of images all floated left, with a 'no-wrap' property on the container. Due to some fairly complex responsive techniques, I've got a holder image hanging offscreen.

You can see this in action here: [Preview Here](http://hammr.co/5628685/6/index.html)

The only problem is when you look at this in IE9 - **if you click to the right of the third image the list will shift left, exposing the holder image offscreen**.

I've tried disabling text selection, I've tried to overriding the mousedown - nothing seems to work and I can't see how to diagnose it.

Any ideas of what I can look into?